# Sinatra - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I've only been able to find rails answers to this question. Whenever I run `rake db:migrate` I am getting the aforementioned error. As far as I am aware, I have setup everything correctly so have no idea what's wrong.

#### config/environment.rb

```
ENV['SINATRA_ENV'] ||= "development"

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default, ENV['SINATRA_ENV'])

configure :develpoment do
    set :database, 'sqlite3:db/database.db'
end

require './app'
```

#### Rakefile

```
require "./config/environment"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

Comment: I think `:develpoment` is spelled wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I checked over it multiple times and missed that!