# Sinatra app raises "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found." on db:migrate using database.yaml

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite, sinatra

I have a sinatra app and i want to configure my development, test and production databases with a `database.yaml` file.

Adding this to my `app.rb` file and running `rake db:migrate` works just fine:

```
configure :development do
    set :database, "sqlite3:forum-service.sqlite3"
end
```

But i want to keep database configurations separated in a `database.yaml` file to keep a cleaner code. If i remove the code above and add the `config/database.yaml` file, as shown below, and run `rake db:migrate` i get:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.
```

my config/database.yaml file

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/forum_dev_sqlite3.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/forum_test_sqlite3.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/forum_prod_sqlite3.db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

my Rakefile

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require './app'
require 'rake/testtask'

task :default do
    puts 'type \'rake --tasks\' to list options.'
end

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
    #t.pattern = "tests/**.rb"
    t.libs << "test"
    t.test_files = FileList['tests/unittest.rb']  # test*.rb for all
    t.verbose = true
end
```

according to Sinatra docs [sinatra/databases/postgresql-activerecord](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/databases/postgresql-activerecord?#article)  by making a `config/database.yaml` file the configurations gets automatically loaded but looks like theres something missing to make the connection possible. Maybe add something to my rakefile to read the configs?

I've seen [Sinatra, Puma, ActiveRecord: No connection pool with 'primary' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401809/sinatra-activerecordconnectionnotestablished-no-connection-pool-for-activer?rq=1) and [Sinatra - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47401809/sinatra-activerecordconnectionnotestablished-no-connection-pool-for-activer?rq=1) but they do not apply for this problem.

Comment: I think you want `database.yml` not `database.yaml`

Comment: @spike they´re the same. You can hold YAML content in files with .yml or yaml

Comment: check out https://github.com/janko/sinatra-activerecord/blob/0f079e6000d2b3b00c642ab9af971466e401ba90/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb#L21 — sinatra is looking for .yml explicitly.

Comment: Added an answer with that after testing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sinatra-activerecord looks in config/database.yml (not yaml) by default. You can change to any other path with the `:database_file` configuration option.

```
  set :database_file, 'config/database.yaml'
```